# Trying to Fix Dependency warning in React Hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-usecallback

I built this React Hook to monitor the current window size so that large displayed images can be automatically resized to the space available:

```
import * as React from 'react';

import type { Rectangle } from 'utils/globalTypes';

/**
 * This is a React Hook implementation of the window.onresize function.
 * 
 * @param {number} horizontalMargin
 * @param {number} verticalMargin
 * @returns windowSize: Rectangle
 */
export const useWindowSize = (horizontalMargin: number = 0,  verticalMargin: number = 0) => {
  const getWindowSize = React.useCallback(() => {
    const {innerWidth, innerHeight} = window;
    return {width: innerWidth - horizontalMargin, height: innerHeight - verticalMargin};
  }, [horizontalMargin, verticalMargin]);

  const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = React.useState<Rectangle>(getWindowSize());

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const handleWindowResize = () => {
      setWindowSize(getWindowSize());
    };

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize); // Cleanup function
    };
  }, [getWindowSize]);

  return [ windowSize ] as const;
};
```

I'm now getting this warning: `Line 16:3:  The 'getWindowSize' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 31) change on every render. To fix this, wrap the definition of 'getWindowSize' in its own useCallback() Hook  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

So, I have wrapped `getWindowSize` in a `useCallback`.  Did I not do it correctly?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue as you describe it with the above code snippet. Here's a running [codesandbpx](https://codesandbox.io/s/trying-to-fix-dependency-warning-in-react-hook-hkydgc). Maybe you could try creating a *running* codeandbox demo of your own that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese makes sense ... I have deleted the answer for no more confusion ... Good learnings always from you 